# How to combine CSV files

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, sed, csv

I have CSV files which are in a form of:

```
1.csv
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
2.csv
2,4,5,7,8,8,9,5
3.csv
2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

.....

up to `18.csv`.

I want the result in `result.csv` to be:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,2,4,5,7,8,8,9,5,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

I tried `cat` but it appends one another after only. I also want to transpose the CSV such that `1.csv` is converted to:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the result.csv file with:

```
for i in {1..18}; do paste $i.csv; done | paste -s > result.csv
```

Or with cat:

```
for i in {1..18}; do cat $i.csv; done | paste -s > result.csv
```

(Put all together with paste/cat and then format the output with `-s` in order to have it in one line.)

Avoiding the loop:

```
cat {1..18}.csv | paste -s > result.csv
```

To transpose 1.csv:

```
sed 's/,/\n/g' 1.csv
```

(Just convert commas by carriage return)

Comment: Is it a way to transpose my csv file?

Comment: `sed 's/,/\n/g' 1.csv`

Comment: Note, instead of the for loop: `cat {1..18}.csv`

Answer (score 1):

Parte1:

```
paste -d, {1..18}.csv
```

for generic transposition use datamash:

```
cat {1..3}.csv | datamash -t, transpose
1,2,2
2,4,3
3,5,4
4,7,5
5,8,6
6,8,7
7,9,8
8,5,9
```